# Creating a reactjs app that uses google cloud-vision

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to create a Reactjs app that uses google-cloud-vision but I am struggling to get the sample-code to work. I have just started learning React-js so I am a bit lost understanding how the sample-code that is created for Node.Js chould be changed to make it work.

I have started by visiting https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries?authuser=1&hl=sv and enabled all the required things (billing and enabled the api). I then created a new service-account and downloaded the json-file.

Then I used the command "npx create-react-app cloud-vision" to create a new project on my computer. I created a credentials folder in the root of the project where I placed the json-file. 
I created a .env file where I entered the environment variable:

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Development\Projects\cloud-vision\credentials\My First Project-b38ff120f2ad.json"

I then installed the cloud-vision npm by using the command: 
npm install --save @google-cloud/vision

Next step was to find the sample-code for the OCR that I want to use from https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?authuser=1&hl=sv

Then I tried npm start

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import testImage from './images/image--002.png'
import vision from '@google-cloud/vision'

function App() {

  const googleVison = async () => {
    // const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

    // Creates a client
    const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

    /**
     * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
     */
    const fileName = testImage;

    // Performs text detection on the local file
    const [result] = await client.textDetection(fileName);
    const detections = result.textAnnotations;
    console.log('Text:');
    detections.forEach(text => console.log(text));
  }

googleVison()

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As I am new to React and don't really get Node.js I was mostly hoping for something to show in the console that I could understand so that I could do some more research. My first problem is that I don't know how to substitute "const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');" so I tried just importing it. 
Is that right? Also I don't know if I just can use the Node.js code as it is or if I must alter it in some way. 
But if I look in the console when the app starts I get an error saying: "Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Development\Projects\cloud-vision\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src"

I then tried npm installing http2 also but just got a new error (Which I cant remember, but I can try that again if that is important to get the app working.)

Can anyone give me some advice of how to get the app running?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, React won't recognise your env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. You have to use a prefix `REACT_APP_` for all custom env variables.

What you need to do is to specify your Google `projectId` and the JSON key file as `credentials` when initialising your
`vision client` like below:

```js
const options = { 
    credentials = require('/path/to/key/json'),
    projectId = 'Your Google Cloud Project ID'
};
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(options);
```